# Getting tail of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

How could I go about getting the tail of a vector:

```
std::vector<int> Example {1,2,3,4,5};

//head = [1]
//tail = [2,3,4,5]
```

Python:

```
head = Array[0]
tail = Array[1:]
```

Haskell

```
myRecursiveFunction :: [Int] -> [Int]
myRecursiveFunction (x : xs) = x + 1 : myRecursiveFunction xs
```

I'm aware I could use an iterative STL algorithm, such as accumulate:

```
std::vector<int> Example {1,2,3,4,5};
std::accumulate(Example.begin() + 1, Example.end(), 0);
```

However this seems quite verbose, are there simpler solutions? I don't mind if the solution copies or views the tail, I'm just looking for a method to easily access the tail of a vector without using iterators.

Comment: Define "getting the tail of a vector". "[1:]" is meaningless, in C++. `std::accumulate` does not extract some portion of a vector, it performs an operation on the vector's range.

Comment: How many different interpretations are there of 'tail of a vector'?

Comment: @BabraCunningham 1. a view of the tail,  2. a copy of the tail

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think the question makes it clear that "tail" means "everything except the first element" in this case

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: "Tail" is very common term used in functional programming languages, and is not "meaningless babble" unless you're ignorant about the functional programming paradigm.

Comment: I should just point out that you can "access" the vector without slicing or otherwise.  Just use the `operator[]`, beginning at 1.  Or since vector data is contiguous in memory, you can get `Example.data()+1` and just work with pointers.

Comment: If this is part of some linear algebra project, there are a number of C++ linear algebra libraries that have their own implementation of "vector" with operations for obtaining subranges or slices. Eigen and Boost.uBlas are among a whole bunch of libraries that are too numerous to list here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `accumulate`.  That doesn't even do what you want.  Just use the vector constructor:

```
std::vector<int>( example.begin() + 1, example.end() );
```

This builds a new vector in memory, and copies from element 1 to the end.  If you want an actual identifier for it:

```
std::vector<int> example_slice( example.begin() + 1, example.end() );
```

If you're trying to pass these around for some kind of recursive process.  You might want to reconsider.  Maybe we're dealing with an XY problem here.

Answer (score 4):

If by "getting the tail of the vector" you mean removal of first element or first n elements, use `vector::erase` :

```
example.erase(example.begin());  // remove the first element
```

-- or --

```
example.erase(example.begin(), example.begin()+n);  // remove the first n elements
```

If by "getting the tail of the vector" you mean saving its tail to another vector, use the range constructor:

```
vector<int> tail(example.begin()+n, example.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest to Python that I can think of is [`std::slice`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/slice/):

```
std::valarray<int> Example {1,2,3,4,5};

auto head = Example[std::slice(0, 1, 1)];
auto tail = Example[std::slice(1, Example.size() - 1, 1)];
```

Not as simple as Python, but closer than your own example.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is no "pretty way" to get clear tail without copying it to another vector, so it may be quite ineffective. If you want to use this tail in read-only way, you may want just save two iterators for tail first and last elements:

```
auto tailBegin = Example.begin() + 1;
auto tailEnd = Example.end();
```